# Fancy Box Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to pin with fancy box is not working. I followed the directions on this link...

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

```
<h5 class="product-title">$25.00 Off First Lyft Ride</h5>
<p class="product-desciption">Get a free $25.00 towards your ride with Lyft when you use the activation code below! If you need a return ride make sure to use the Uber Promo Codes, and get a free ride back!<br><br><font size="2"><b><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyJsb4ANIy8"><font color="#858585">Watch Video Review<font></a></b></font></p>
```

All javascript and link rels are correct. A class looks correct as well. Any ideas?

Web page is www.couponcodeshero.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to use youtube.com like :

```
    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>
```

Also i have found error in your console for fancybox. Error is :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

So this means that you have not found `fancybox.js` file data on this page. OR your **fancybox js jQuery** is **conflicting** with other **jQuery library**.